# VLC Media Player - Change step size of timelapse

Tags: vlc-media-player

Is it possible to change the step size of time lapses to make it more precise?
E.g. if you watch a clip with VLC media player and press `Numpad -` then the video plays with `0.67x` times slower, if you press again, then `0.50x` and so on.

Is it possible to make it more precise? E.g. lower the steps by `0.05x` on each press?

**Why do I need it?**

I have converted old video tapes to a digital format. However some parts are much faster and I need to slow the video down. However, if I slow down then it directly goes to `0.67x` times slower, which is way too slow.

Is it possible to hack the software or extend it to get the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "-" key is for Slower speed from 1.00x it slows down to
0.67x, 0.50x, 0.33x, 0.25x, 0.12x, 0.06x, 0.03x, and 0.02x

You can use the "[" key for Slower(fine) changes from 1.00x it slows down to
0.90x, 0.80x, 0.70x, 0.60x, 0.50x, 0.40x, 0.30x, 0.20x, 0.10x, and 0.03x

Not 0.05x but 0.10x.